# Asp.net handle custom urls

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Suppose a website with a Default.aspx page.

These addresses find the Default.aspx physical file and load it:

**www.mysite.com**

**www.mysite.com/Default.aspx**

It's clear that we'll get the **error 404** with this address:
**www.mysite.com/myvariable**

Is there any way (any configuration) to make this address call the default.aspx file and ignore the /myvariable part? (or in some cases get the /myvariable value in the default.aspx.cs for example?)

As I know it could be possible in asp.net MVC, but I need to do so in **asp.net web forms**.

Note that the site contains other pages like info.aspx, contactus.aspx, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use routing with webforms too.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes, correct. I didn't know that's it's possible for web forms too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what SLaks said, we use [MapPageRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "{myvariable}", "~/Default.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "info", "~/Info.aspx");
}
```